# How to change TEXT of Done and Cancel button of select Field in sencha touch 2 framework

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, translation

I need to translate buttons of all selectField in my application. What I have done:

```
Ext.override(Ext.Picker, {
    doneButton: 'Terminer',
    cancelButton: 'Annuler'
});
```

Not working.

And...

```
{
   xtype: 'selectfield',
   name: 'default_language',
    options: [
        {text: 'English', value: 'en'},
        {text: 'Francais',  value: 'fr'}
    ],
    doneButton: {
        text: "Terminer"
    }
}
```

Not working...

Any others idea ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a configuration for both Phones/Tablets, Voila : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-cfg-defaultPhonePickerConfig

```
{
        xtype : 'selectfield',
        label : 'My Label',
        defaultPhonePickerConfig : {
            doneButton : 'You Button Text!',
            cancelButton : 'You Button Text!'
        },
        options                  : [
            { text : 'First Option',  value : 'first'  },
            { text : 'Second Option', value : 'second' },
            { text : 'Third Option',  value : 'third'  }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: @VWGolf2 Worked for me. Upvoted. How to change class?